# how to read(see) html in my android's gmail?/ Gmail

Tags: android

I am sending one mail to my gmail account. This mail contains my custom scheme url(so when this link will be clicked I will be able to activate my installed application on device).
However I am unable to click this url because when I open my gmail in android device it simply shows me simple text Like this :-

Hi, You can download your book here :- This will be my link.

Now "This will be my link" does not appear to be a link so I am unable to click this and so can not open my application.

My question here is how can I read(see) html in my android's gmail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't just an Android question - the GMail website doesn't let you click URL's with unknown schemes either.

There is no changing this behavior to my knowledge.  However, you can configure your Android app to respond to URL's from your web site instead.  So if you have the web site http://mywebsite.com/ then you can set your app to handle all URL's that start with http://mywebsite.com/app/.  Users can click these links in GMail, and if they have your app installed it will open your app.  If they don't, it will load the browser and go to your web site - where you can tell them they need to install your app. = )

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick response, actually I was also little confused about this so in title I put android's gmail/Gmail. OK.
So now for handling this feature Do I need to have one website?

Comment: Well, it would probably be rude to handle URL's for a web site that doesn't belong to you, so I'd recommend having a web site.  It'd be nice if GMail would let you use your own custom scheme, but since you have to use http: you should follow the rules for http: and make sure you own whatever domain you are using.

Answer (score 0):

As I was trying to implement custom scheme url(Appcelerator titanium) but my email was unable to read that url as link so I added **http://** starting of my url so now my email shows this as url and now I am able to click this url in respond my application successfully opens.

My focus was to make one common link so that no matter its iOS or android if user clicks this link my installed application will be opened. But adding http:// in iOS will never open your application it will always be directed to browser(that what I read). So right now I am keeping two different links for different OS.